# Some fields are not sorting properly in view

Tags: 7, views

I'm trying to create a directory list in view. But some of the fields are not properly sorting.

**See the below image for my view configuration.**

[image]

**And the output of the view.**

[image]

**Update:**  Style setting

[image]

**Update:**  Field Settings

[image]

**Grouping**

[image][image]

Please anyone help me to get the correct output.

Comment: I think problem with the grouping. Add a screenshot of style setting too.

Comment: Why do you have the `content: title` field two time in your fields section?

Comment: @Djouuuuh That one title is for grouping.

Comment: Yes sorry I understood that just after asking actually ;)

Comment: @SumitMadan I've updated the question

Comment: Not field style setting. Your views format settings.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the sorting. There is a problem with your grouping. Can you show us that, as well as the field settings for the field you are grouping  on, like are you rewriting anything?

Comment: Also please check if any of your node titles start with a space.

Comment: @J.Reynolds I've updated the question. I'll check the node. I think may be that is the problem.

Comment: @J.Reynolds, Thank you for your suggestion, Actually I had space before the content title.

Comment: How to you group the items with letters, if you group with **Content: Title**?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not a configuration problem.  Examine the nodes that aren't sorting correctly.  They likely have spaces at the beginning of their titles.